# Neo4j poor performance on ORDER BY

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have query like this

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[s:KNOWS]->(t:Person) WHERE s.state = "blocked"
WITH DISTINCT (t) AS user
SKIP 0
LIMIT 10
MATCH (user)<-[r:KNOWS { state: "blocked" }]-(p:Person)
RETURN user.username, SIZE(COLLECT(p.username)) as count
```

[image]

First problem is when I have SKIP for example 100, it's getting slower, any idea why?

Seconds problem is, when I try to add ORDER BY, for example ORDER BY p.createdAt which is date (indexed field), it's always timing out.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using please?

Comment: We are using 3.5.13

Comment: Where are you trying to put the `ORDER BY` clause? Can you show that query?

Comment: MATCH (p:Person)-[s:KNOWS]->(t:Person) WHERE s.state = "blocked"
WITH DISTINCT (t) AS user
ORDER BY s.createdAt DESC
SKIP 0
LIMIT 10
MATCH (user)<-[r:KNOWS { state: "blocked" }]-(p:Person)
RETURN user.username, SIZE(COLLECT(p.username)) as count

Answer (score 2):

You might have better performance with a tweak to your initial MATCH:

```
MATCH (t:Person) 
WHERE ()-[:KNOWS {state:"blocked"}]->(t)
WITH t AS user // no longer need DISTINCT here
...
```

For better performance you might consider creating a [fulltext schema index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/schema/index/#schema-index-fulltext-search) on :KNOWS relationships by their state property, and use the fulltext index query procedure to do this initial lookup (this is assuming :KNOWS relationships always connect two :Person nodes).

Comment: your cypher is missing the closing bracket on the rel property

Comment: I don't follow why full text index here is better then normal index? I don't need fulltext search on this property, it will be always exact value.

Comment: Currently Neo4j doesn't have indexing on relationships, except via fulltext schema indexes on the relationship. All other indexes are on nodes only. An index lookup should be quicker than checking all :KNOWS relationships from every :Person node and filtering on the property.